# QObject::connect: No such signal mouseReleaseEvent

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qt5

I'm trying:

```
  connect(myButton, SIGNAL(mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)),
    this, SLOT(ShowContextMenu(QMouseEvent*)));
```

but getting error message:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)
```

qt 5.4 - what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: ***what am I doing wrong there?*** mouseReleaseEvent is not a signal so you can not connect it to a slot.

Comment: @drescherjm so to catch right click I need something alike my own button?

Comment: If you make your button inherit from QToolButton you should be able to handle the mouseReleaseEvent and emit your own signal. I am not sure if there is a simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that myButton is of the class QPushButton, you can use the released() signal:

```
connect(myButton, SIGNAL(released()),
    this, SLOT(ShowContextMenu()));
```

Assuming that the slot 'ShowContextMenu' can be called without an argument.
See also the QT Documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that... So you mean like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658464/qt-rightclick-qpushbutton)?