# Retrieve the right clicked QPushButton object name in qt

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I already have this function to retrieve the clicked `QPushButton` object name:

```
void MainWindow::clickedBtnInfo()
{
    QPushButton *btnSender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); // retrieve the button you have clicked
    QString *clickedBtnName = btnSender->objectName(); // retrive the object name from the clicked button
    qDebug() << clickedBtnName;
}
```

And I checked this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658464/qt-rightclick-qpushbutton) to implement the `rightClicked` signal.

But I want to know what I can do to retrieve the `QPushButton` object name which is right clicked. 
 Thanks.

An edit of how I implement the `rightClicked` signal:

```
void MainWindow::onRightClicked()
{
    qDebug() << "User right clicked me";
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
        emit rightClicked();
    }
}
```

And connect like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(rightClicked()), this, SLOT(onRightClicked()));
```

Sorry for not explaining my question completely before. BTW, I am just very new to Qt, So hope to get some specifically explained answers.
 Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may add more code , the main problem of your question is not visible here

Comment: @saeed I added the code of how I implement that. I appreciate your answers, and I tried your following answers. But those may seem kind of complicated for me to understand and implement.

Comment: You have connected MainWindow signal and slots , as i understand your question you want to recognized pushbutton right click , the slot onRightClicked will enter when you right click on mainwindow form not pushbutton if you want to handle click and right click of pushbutton you should connect pushbutton signals.

Comment: you can post more codes if not you may mail me at saeedsoleimanifar@gmail to see whole codes you have done, if possible

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided in the question does the right thing. You need to extend `QPushButton` and **not** `QMainWindow`! Simply copy the sources from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15658863/3767076 into your project (if you need both clicks, check the comment below).

After that, you can use the `QRightClickButton` instead of a `QPushButton`. If you created your UI with the designer, you can right-click the button in the ui and set it as placeholder for `QRightClickButton`.